# How to implement SSL Pinning in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am little bit confuse to implement SSL pinning in my iOS app. I read many articles some are saying implement with Certificate and some are saying implement with public key.

I have some doubts:

1. Which method is best for SSL pinning?
2. How to get Certificate and public key?

It helps me a lot if any one have example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for late, I found the solution [TrustKit](https://github.com/datatheorem/TrustKit)

TrustKit is an open source framework that makes it easy to deploy SSL public key pinning and reporting in any iOS 8+, macOS 10.10+, tvOS 10+ or watchOS 3+ App; it supports both Swift and Objective-C Apps.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out [GCXTrustPolicy](https://github.com/grandcentrix/GCXTrustPolicy)

It is a framework which was developed by some people of the company I am working at. It does certificate pinning and a little more.

Have a look at the code to understand how pinning works.