# iOS 12: validate local certificate with URLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl-certificate

I have a service in the local network with uses custom signed certificate for HTTPS connection. I have the certificate (cer, p12, der, whatever, they are all convertible to each other). Question is what should I write in didReceiveChallenge when receiveing a chellenge of NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate?

And NO, I don't want to use NSAllowsArbitraryLoads, that would be a security breach. I'm about to use NSAllowsLocalNetworking so far.

```c
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession*)session
    didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge*)challenge
      completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential* _Nullable))completionHandler {
    bool handled = false;

    // Always trust any server name (which is an IP address actually)
    NSLog(@"method: %@", challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod);
    if (challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust) {
        SecTrustRef trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
        if (trust != nullptr) {
            completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:trust]);
            handled = true;
        }
    }
    else if (challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate) {
        NSString* cerFile = [NSBundle.mainBundle pathForResource:@"dev" ofType:@"der"];
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cerFile];
        SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, (CFDataRef)data);


        // here I have to somehow validate using existing certificate...

    }

    if (!handled) {
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling, nil);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in TrustKit https://github.com/datatheorem/TrustKit. It is the defacto standard for certificate validation and pinning.

For example code will be something like this:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        let validator = configureTrustKit().pinningValidator
        if(!validator.handle(challenge, completionHandler: completionHandler)){
            completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
        }
    }

func configureTrustKit()->TrustKit{
        let config = [kTSKPinnedDomains:
            [URLRepository.baseURL.host: [kTSKIncludeSubdomains: true,
                                          kTSKEnforcePinning: true,
                                          kTSKPublicKeyHashes: 

    URLRepository.pinForCurrentStage
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            return TrustKit(configuration: config)
        }
```

URLSession or frameworks like Alamofire have similar callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that "certificate pinning" is what you seek for.
It well described [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1484288-preventing-man-in-the-middle-attacks-in-ios-with-ssl-pinning) and there SO answers too, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50171916/how-to-implement-ssl-pinning-in-ios).

If you in doubt about hardcode public key of server in app (as described in first link), then I think it is quite Ok, because, well, public key is public.